# SetForegroundWindow problems when a modal child exists

Tags: .net, windows, winapi

I am using the Win32 API call `SetForegroundWindow` to set focus to another application's window. I am then using `SendKeys` to send keystrokes to that window.

This works well apart from when a modal window (such as a File Open dialog) is open. In this scenario I want to set that modal child window as the foreground window.

Using my main application's hWnd, how can I set any modal child window as the active window? (Note that there may be a modal child that itself has another modal child open, so ideally I would like things to work in this scenario as well).

I am coding this in C#, .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GetTopWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633514(VS.85).aspx) will give you the highest Z-order decedent of a given HWND, which would be the last modal dialog in the event one exists.

[GetLastActivePopup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633507%28VS.85%29.aspx) will also work.

Answer (score 2):

See the [GetLastActivePopup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633507%28VS.85%29.aspx) API.